# Where to find BGI file?

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, bgi

I am trying to plot circle using *graphics.h* library but all the tutorials and examples I have seen had *"C:\TurboC\BGI"* in the *initgraph()* function. As long I understand, the mentioned path leads to the graphics driver, but in my my PC I was unable to find any *BGI* file.

I am using mingw-w64 environment on visual studio code.
Is there any different command or add-on I should install to access graphics programming in c++?

It would be a lot of help, if anyone can suggest any alternative way to do graphics programming in c++.

Comment: ***I am using mingw-w64 environment on visual studio code.*** You will probably run into many issues running this code which was compiled with a 2005 version of gcc-3

Comment: ***if anyone can suggest any alternative way to do graphics programming in c++.*** Yes please don't use this highly obsolete graphics library that was designed in the 1980s for a compiler that no longer exists. You may want to look at SFML or SDL. [https://www.libsdl.org/](https://www.libsdl.org/) [https://www.sfml-dev.org/](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) you may also want to look at this list for other recommended open source c++ libraries: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://github.com/ananay/turboc OR download Turbo C++ software then use the installation location (which is C:/ in above example) /TurboC/BGI

BGI files come with Turbo C++